# Handlebars unable to render certain properties of an object

Tags: javascript, object, web, handlebars.js

I'm having a really spooky problem with handlebars - and I'm wondering if anyone has run into this before.

I have an object that I'm trying to use handlebars to render - and despite all of the properties pulling across in `{{this}}` - some properties won't render/show.

> How the object looks in the database

[image]

> The Handlebars rendering code

```
{{#each category.categories}}
  <h1>Complete object</h1>
  {{this}}
  <br>
  <br>
  {{id}} {{!-- String --}}
  {{confidence}} {{!-- String --}}
  {{depth}} {{!-- Number --}}
  {{original_name}} {{!-- String --}}
  {{!-- these can't be accessed --}}
  {{category_1}} {{!-- String --}}
  {{category_2}} {{!-- String --}}
  {{category_3}} {{!-- String --}}
  {{classification}} {{!-- Array --}}
{{/each}}
```

[image]

---

> How it renders on the page

[image]

> How it looks in inspector

[image]

---

I've been pulling my hair out at this - and I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help/insights anyone might have

~Ollie

Comment: Strange! Could you please share your sample JSON data here?

Comment: Do you have one error in console ? Anything else that could help a bit more, I'm pretty sure that if I do a snippet to run this I won't get an error so I think we need more information.